# How much space do I need to upgrade from Vista Home Premium to Ultimate?

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

I have Vista Home Premium (64-bit) installed at the moment. How much free space would I need to upgrade it to Vista Ultimate (64-bit)? I ask this because I don't want to go through a complete re-format and clean install at the moment, and I have limited free space on the system disk.

Comment: The upgrade process should tell you.  Technically you already have everything.  There a reason you are upgrading Vista to Ultimate instead of upgrading to Windows 7 instead?

Comment: Also remember that you need an UPGRADE key to change the edition for an upgrade

Comment: Thanks! It's because I don't have a license for Windows 7. Vista Home Premium and Vista Ultimate share most of the features but they are not the same products. I have had an upgrade license for Vista Ultimate for some time now, but I never used it. I want to upgrade to Ultimate to get access to things like group policy. It's an annoyance to have to go through the registry to perform such trivial administrative tasks. By the way, why would I upgrade to  Windows 7 and not Windows 8? Thankfully Windows 8 will come in only 2 different versions, as opposed to Vista and 7.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The minimum requirement is 16 GB (or 15915 MB). This is what it says in the upgrade process.